# Jekyll won't generate links

Tags: jekyll

In my jekyll posts, if I try to add a link like this:

```
Here's a link to [Google](http://www.google.com).
```

and run:

```
jekyll build
```

I should see a link on that post, but instead I see this exact text:

```
Here's a link to [Google](http://www.google.com).
```

Why isn't it generating a link?

I thought it might be the version of markdown I've specified in my _config.yml, but I've tried maruku, kramdown, and redcarpet.

Also, the same thing is happening with images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the extension on my posts was .html instead of .markdown or .md

I fixed that and it works great.